# pandas read malformed CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, separator, malformed

I received a CSV file where `,` is the separator used to separate fields, but unfortunately additional as the symbol denoting the decimal point (german notation).

As a result, some rows will have a different number of columns. Strangely excel will parse /read the file rather fine. Is it possible to read such files in pandas as well? So far I only got something similar to

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 97 fields in line 3, saw 98
```

## edit

Here is a minimal example:

```
pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/foo.csv'), sep=',', decimal=',')
```

with `~/Downloads/foo.csv` file with the content of

```
first, number, third
some, 1, other
foo, 1.5, bar
baz, 1,5, some
```

When I load the data in R

```
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
Warnung: 1538 parsing failures.
row col   expected      actual
  1  -- 93 columns 97 columns 
  2  -- 93 columns 98 columns 
  3  -- 93 columns 97 columns 
  4  -- 93 columns 102 columns
  5  -- 93 columns 99 columns
```

Is there such a permissive mode in pandas?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible sample data set?

Comment: done. please see the edit.

Comment: Is this an accurate representation of the data in that there's only one potentially affected column per row?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It could be multiple.

Comment: But the header resembles the correct number of columns.

Comment: Does your DF contain __multiple__ numeric columns with potentially malformed numbers?

Comment: Indeed. That's true.

Comment: Do you at least have that no two potentially malformed columns are contiguous?  (So that we wouldn't have to figure out if 2,3,4 was 2,3.4 or 2.3,4?)

Comment: In your example data there is a space after each comma that's a separator, but for the numeric values there is no space.  Is your file actually like that?  If so, you should be able to read it in with something like `sep=',\s'`.

Comment: Will need to try that.

Comment: Great idea. Unfortunately, the assumption that columns are cleanly separated will not hold true for the real data.

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv(..., error_bad_lines=False`)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there is no quote delimiter in your file that you should declare to read_csv.

If you file is ill-formed, there is mathematically no deterministic algorithm than can decide if one succession of characters with a comma is two fields, or just one with a comma separated number.

You will have to write a preprocessor that does a clean-up of the ill-formed data with an ad-hoc algorithm approaching the reality of you file. That can be nasty like *I take the assumption digits followed by comma followed by 3 digits are actually the same field* and any other variation of these fixes.

You can also face cases where even that won't be deterministic, then you have no way but to go to the data source and ask for another file format of for data fix.

To drop the wrong lines and load the other ones, these parameters from the documentation will help:

> error_bad_lines : boolean, default True Lines with too many fields
> (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will by default cause an
> exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will be returned. If False,
> then these “bad lines” will dropped from the DataFrame that is
> returned. (Only valid with C parser)
>
> warn_bad_lines : boolean, default
> True If error_bad_lines is False, and warn_bad_lines is True, a
> warning for each “bad line” will be output. (Only valid with C
> parser).

Comment: unfortunately this sounds like an answer.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler believe my humble experience in that field, not only it sounds like it but your mind will not accept for a bit of time there is no alternative :-). If you think about it more, you'll see that solving this generically is congruent to violating the halting problem.

Comment: may I ask additionally to find (see my last edit) a similar permissive mode to R which will only throw warnings but still load parts of the data?